# Generate JWT form header and payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm Using node js to create a jwt in my backend server.
I'm using a library to sign/verify a JWT and it work fine. once one jwt.io i paste the token that i got when i sign in and i can see my data in the payload. 
So the problem is that I'm trying to generate the signature from header and the payload that i got back in jwt.io
here is what i tryed to do but it did'nt work and i'm confuse a bit.
the algorith used to sign is the default one HS256.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

// encode base64 the header
let jsonHeader = JSON.stringify({
  alg: "HS256",
  typ: "JWT",
});
let bs64header = Buffer.from(jsonHeader).toString("base64").split("=")[0];
console.log("bs64header :>>\n ", bs64header); //look the same as the token i got

// encode vase64 the payload
let jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({
  id: "5eb20004ac94962628c68b91",
  iat: 1589125343,
  exp: 1589989343,
  jti: "37743739b1476caa18ca899c7bc934e1aba63ba1",
});
let bs64payload = Buffer.from(jsonPayload).toString("base64").split("=")[0];
console.log("bs64Payload :>> \n", bs64payload); //look the same as the token i got

// TRY to generate the signature from the Base64Header and Base64Payload
// with the secret code that i used to sign the JWT
let secret = "0d528cb666023eee0d44e725fe9dfb751263d2f68f07998ae7388ff43b1b504f";
let signature = bs64header + "." + bs64payload;

let hashed = crypto
  .createHash("sha256", secret)
  .update(signature)
  .digest("hex");

console.log("hashed :>> \n", hashed);

let bs64signature = Buffer.from(hashed).toString("base64").split("=")[0];
console.log("bs64signature>>", bs64signature); //This is where i got stuck.

// let jwt = bs64header + "." + bs64payload + "." + bs64signature;
// console.log("jwt>>", jwt);
```

Comment: Why are you generating a jwt string by yourself ?? I guess you need to look into the https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken. This will reduce your code a lot and all the manual steps that you are doing to create the token. Tokens are really sensitive, one mistake to the structure and you will not be able to verify or read it.

Comment: i was using the jwt.sign() to create the token and jwt.verify() to check if the token is good. But when i wanted to create a Logout root for the user those two methodes was not safe. so i needed to creat my own token with some custom claims in the Payload to make some verification later !

Comment: You can add custom claims while you are creating tokens via JSONWebToken lib. What do you exactly mean by the fact the methods are not safe ? You could have provided a role scope within your token to check what kind of a user it is.

Comment: Actually i was my fault by not making more researchs about JWT and try to understand it. Also I agree with your fist comment, using the  npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken will be more usefull too. but at the this was a good exercice helping to have a better understing on how JWT work and how to make it by your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your code a lot to make it less repetitive and easier to read. I am not entirely sure if this will work, so please comment if there are any errors.

I have tested it in [runkit](https://runkit.com/zera/jwt) and have also checked what the output should be using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlYjIwMDA0YWM5NDk2MjYyOGM2OGI5MSIsImlhdCI6MTU4OTEyNTM0MywiZXhwIjoxNTg5OTg5MzQzLCJqdGkiOiIzNzc0MzczOWIxNDc2Y2FhMThjYTg5OWM3YmM5MzRlMWFiYTYzYmExIn0.HcbKqTBB0oFoTgIVAZ6yax06O8sjM5Cp_g6vwLMFNFk). The output appears to be the same, so I am pretty certain that this works.

**Changes**

- Created a function to *base64* encode objects and strings.
- Created a function to make *base64* strings use the URL safe character set.
- Changed [`crypto.createHash()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options) to [`crypto.createHmac()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key_options), so that a secret key can actually be used.

```
// base64 encode the data
function bs64encode(data) {
  if (typeof data === "object") {
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  return bs64escape(Buffer.from(data).toString("base64"));
}

// modify the base64 string to be URL safe
function bs64escape(string) {
  return string.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=/g, "");
}



// base64 encode the header
let bs64header = bs64encode({
  alg: "HS256",
  typ: "JWT"
});

console.log("bs64header :>>\n ", bs64header);


// base64 encode the payload
let bs64payload = bs64encode({
  id: "5eb20004ac94962628c68b91",
  iat: 1589125343,
  exp: 1589989343,
  jti: "37743739b1476caa18ca899c7bc934e1aba63ba1"
});

console.log("bs64payload :>> \n", bs64payload);


// generate the signature from the header and payload
let secret = "0d528cb666023eee0d44e725fe9dfb751263d2f68f07998ae7388ff43b1b504f";
let signature = bs64header + "." + bs64payload;

let bs64signature = bs64escape(crypto
  .createHmac("sha256", secret)
  .update(signature)
  .digest("base64"));

console.log("bs64signature>>", bs64signature);


let jwt = bs64header + "." + bs64payload + "." + bs64signature;

console.log("jwt>>", jwt);
```

Comment: Thanks!! This work too. I also a solution before I check your answer. So what i was missing was this 
- Created a function to make base64 strings use the URL safe character set.
- Changed crypto.createHash() to crypto.createHmac(), so that a secret key can actually be used.